# Launch an application on the iOS simulator with using command line

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, terminal, ios-simulator

Good Morning,

I am trying to launch an application on the `iOS Simulator` with command line so i put this command in the terminal:

```
open `xcode-select --print-path`/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app
```

With this command, the simulator is launched. My question is how can I start an application from the terminal?

Comment: This may help: http://cocoamanifest.net/articles/2011/12/running-your-ios-app-in-the-simulator-from-the-command-line.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used `WaxSim` (referenced in rog's comment) and it works pretty well.  You can find it at https://github.com/square/WaxSim.  For what it's worth, there have been no commits for something like two years and there are a number of open pull requests.

Recently I have started using `ios-sim` which can be found at https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim.  It looks like (currently) it is active and seems to have more functionality.  So far, I haven't had any problems with it (although I have not used it *in anger* yet).

Comment: i have note your solution but i have to lunch my application with simulator 6.0 !! i don't know but with WaxSim i think isn't possible !!

Comment: I'm not sure about `WaxSim` and the simulator in the 6.x SDK, but I do know that `ios-sim` works.

Comment: Good question.  I installed it via the package manager, Homebrew, which you can find at http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/

Answer (score 2):

I do not have enough reps to write it as comment.

`ios-sim` is used by Facebook and lot of other companies for running automated tests and launching stuff via commandline into iOS simulator.

You can download it from the git repo, just open it in XCode and build it.
The executable will be generated in the Build>products folder.
(For XCode 6 ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-sim-xxxxxx.../Build/Products/)
https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim

Here is a command to run the .app in iOS6 simulator:

```
ios-sim launch ./MyApp.app --devicetypeid "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6"
```